# Building a grid of Youtube Videos

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, api, youtube

I am trying to make a grid of youtube videos on a web page, the grid itself will be made up of the thumbnails of the videos - once I click them then the video opens up.

I am nearly at the end but I have hit a major wall which I cant seem to get past - i am an amateur programmer btw.

So, once I get the json data back from the youtube api, Ive used the datacontractjsonserializer class to store all of the information within classes i have defined. This leaves me with essentially, with an array of items - videos - which i can run through and do whatever.

I want to be able to run through the array of videos, and create a new every time and also add properties to it such as give it a css class etc. This is so that the website is not limited to a certain amount of videos and can display as many as the youtube api returns.

any ideas appreciated thanks,

this is what i have so far;

```
foreach (var vid in playlist.items)
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv =
        new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    createDiv.Style = "float: left";
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage img =
        new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage();
    img.Src = vid.snippet.thumbnails.@default.url;
    img.Border = 0;
    img.Style = "width:80px; height:55px; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px;";
    createDiv.InnerHtml = img;

}
```

The above code simply doesn't compile and even if it did it wouldnt work.

I also created an image for the thumbnail

```
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage img =
                new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage();
            img.Src = vid.snippet.thumbnails.@default.url;
```

which needs to be stored within the div class. I also need them to follow certain css styles-how do i link it to my css sheet?

I am basically trying to replicate

```
         <div class="imgGrid" style="float:left"><a href="XXXX " class="play_youtube iframe" title="XXXX">
             <img src="AAAA " class="thumbnail" style="width: 80px; height: 55px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" border="0" />
             </a>
         </div>
```

within the loop. Where XXXX and AAAA isdata retrieved from the yt api.

As requested, this is an example of a json response

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_mzWJs/b7tV9rFfqslF-60lBe43V9qWMqA\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 26,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_mzWJs/5sFoyW9dWRWrqgXNUY935g7zYGw\"",
   "id": "UkQwOVI4XzJuSnRqZy4wOVI4XzJuSnRqZw==",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-01-14T15:00:11.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Maroon 5 - Sugar",
    "description": "Buy Sugar on iTunes: http://smarturl.it/M5V\n\nTickets for Maroon 5’s North American with Rozzi Crane and European Tour with Nick Gardner are on-sale now! http://www.maroon5.com/\n\nMusic video by Maroon 5 performing Sugar. (C) 2015 Interscope Records",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/09R8_2nJtjg/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/09R8_2nJtjg/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/09R8_2nJtjg/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/09R8_2nJtjg/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "YouTube Spotlight",
    "playlistId": "RD09R8_2nJtjg",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "09R8_2nJtjg"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_mzWJs/8qf4tj_LOI5PwxemtJWYiNACZ5s\"",
   "id": "UkQwOVI4XzJuSnRqZy5PUGYwWWJYcURtMA==",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-11-19T14:00:18.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Mark Ronson - Uptown Funk ft. Bruno Mars",
    "description": "Mark Ronson – Uptown Funk ft. Bruno Mars\nFrom the album Uptown Special, out now: http://smarturl.it/UptownSpecial?IQid=yt \n\n-------------------------\n\nFollow Mark Ronson online:\nWebsite: http://www.markronson.co.uk\nTwitter: http://twitter.com/MarkRonson\nFacebook: http://www.facebook.com/markronson\nInstagram: http://instagram.com/iammarkronson\nSpotify: http://smarturl.it/RonsonStrm?IQid=yt\n\nMusic video by Mark Ronson feat. Bruno Mars performing Uptown Funk. (C) 2014 Sony Music Entertainment UK Ltd.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OPf0YbXqDm0/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OPf0YbXqDm0/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OPf0YbXqDm0/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OPf0YbXqDm0/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "YouTube Spotlight",
    "playlistId": "RD09R8_2nJtjg",
    "position": 1,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "OPf0YbXqDm0"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_mzWJs/k0QjzQlUFBtx9xt7sa3G8xyGFwc\"",
   "id": "UkQwOVI4XzJuSnRqZy5BSnREWElhenJNbw==",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-01-22T08:00:06.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Ellie Goulding - Love Me Like You Do (Official Video)",
    "description": "iTunes: http://ell.li/EGLMLYDiTYT\nSpotify: http://ell.li/LMLYDspotify\n\nFrom the forthcoming Fifty Shades of Grey film and soundtrack.\n\nMore Ellie:\nhttp://www.elliegoulding.com\nhttp://www.facebook.com/elliegoulding\nhttp://www.twitter.com/elliegoulding\nhttp://www.instagram.com/elliegoulding\nhttps://play.spotify.com/user/elliegouldingofficial\n\n\nMusic video by Ellie Goulding performing Love Me Like You Do. (C) 2015 Polydor Ltd. (UK)",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AJtDXIazrMo/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AJtDXIazrMo/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AJtDXIazrMo/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AJtDXIazrMo/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AJtDXIazrMo/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "YouTube Spotlight",
    "playlistId": "RD09R8_2nJtjg",
    "position": 2,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "AJtDXIazrMo"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_mzWJs/eAcdGURRFc7MFSYaeTUSnzUQtU8\"",
   "id": "UkQwOVI4XzJuSnRqZy5lLU9SaEVFOVZWZw==",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-11-10T17:05:44.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Taylor Swift - Blank Space",
    "description": "Watch Taylor's new video for \"Blank Space\".  No animals, trees, automobiles or actors were harmed in the making of this video.  Taylor’s new release 1989 is Available Now on iTunes http://www.smarturl.it/TS1989.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e-ORhEE9VVg/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e-ORhEE9VVg/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e-ORhEE9VVg/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e-ORhEE9VVg/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e-ORhEE9VVg/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "YouTube Spotlight",
    "playlistId": "RD09R8_2nJtjg",
    "position": 3,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "e-ORhEE9VVg"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_mzWJs/v5Vm-iso_u1p8rya8nb-IevUHGQ\"",
   "id": "UkQwOVI4XzJuSnRqZy5scC1FTzVJNjBLQQ==",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-10-07T13:57:37.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Ed Sheeran - Thinking Out Loud [Official Video]",
    "description": "The official video for 'Thinking Out Loud', Ed learnt to dance! \n'x', available to buy via iTunes here: http://smarturl.it/x-itunesdlx\nFeaturing and taught by @dance10Brittany and @dance10Paul\n\nSubscribe to my channel: http://bit.ly/SubscribeToEdSheeran\nGo behind the scenes of the video: http://bit.ly/ThinkingOutLoudBTS\nHear the rest of my album, 'x': http://bit.ly/XOfficialPlaylist\nAudio of 'Thinking Out Loud': http://youtu.be/WpyfrixXBqU\n\nHey German fans! View here: http://smarturl.it/ThinkingOutLoud-DE\n\nBuy on CD & Vinyl here: http://smarturl.it/x-album\nBuy on Google Play: http://smarturl.it/x-googleplaydlx\n\nFollow me on...\nFacebook: http://www.facebook.com/EdSheeranMusic\nTwitter: http://twitter.com/edsheeran\nInstagram: http://instagram.com/teddysphotos\nOfficial Website: http://edsheeran.com",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lp-EO5I60KA/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lp-EO5I60KA/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lp-EO5I60KA/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lp-EO5I60KA/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lp-EO5I60KA/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "YouTube Spotlight",
    "playlistId": "RD09R8_2nJtjg",
    "position": 4,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "lp-EO5I60KA"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem with the above code?

Comment: the code doesnt compile, its as far as ive gotten but even this does nothing. I have also created a htmlimage and set its properties - i need this to be stored within the div class seen above too

Comment: Are you open to some other implementation?  Do you know what is the number of rows and columns of the grid to be displayed, or it has to be decided dynamically based on the browser window size?

Comment: Yes it has to be decided dynamically, also there cannot be a set number of rows and columns as the user can define what playlist they want to play-if they choose a playlist with 100 videos then the page will arrange and place all of the videos onto it accordingly

Comment: could you show us your json response?

Comment: i have included it now

Answer (score 1):

Modified your wrong code:

```
 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    createDiv.Style.Add("float", "left");
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage img =
        new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage();
    img.Src = "Your source code.";
    img.Border = 0;
    img.Style.Add("width", "80px");
    img.Style.Add("margin-right", "10px");
    img.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "10px");
    createDiv.Controls.Add(img);

    tstPanel.Controls.Add(createDiv);
```

aspx:

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="tstPanel"></asp:Panel>
```

Atleast this is compiling and working at my end.

Comment: This gets it working great job, but I see that you have hard coded the style properties, is there a way to make it inherit a css class? Also, how can I add a href to the div? 

I have updated my question to include what i have in my aspx code which i need inside the loop -

Comment: You have to wrap your div within <a> tag to use href.